# Syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash, shell

I run my shell script but return a error "syntax error near unexpected token `done'", I wonder why it is ? The important thing is I can run it in another computer...

See my code below:

```
input=$1
folder=$2
output=$3
while read line
do
  url=`echo $line | awk -F'\t' '{print $2}'`
  id=`echo $line | awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' | sed 's/http:\/\/buy.yahoo.com.tw\/gdsale\/gdsale.asp?gdid=//g'`
  ans=`echo $line | awk -F'\t' '{print $3}'`
  flag=`grep "$ans" $folder/$id".spec"`
  if [ -n "$flag" ]; then
      echo "yes   $line" >> $3
  else
      echo "no    $line" >> $3
  fi
done < $input
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to redirect the input of read from $input?

Comment: There needs to be a space after `sed`.

Comment: Doesn't address your question, but you do not need flag.  Just do: if grep -q ...; then ...

Comment: Also, rather than escaping the '/' in the sed, you can use a different delimeter: 's@http://...@repl@'

Comment: The < $input indeed doesn't look right. What is it meant to do?

Comment: you can reduce the complexity of this significantly with `while read discard url ans discard2 ; do id=$(echo $url | sed 's/..../) ; .... ; done` . Good luck.

Comment: Are you using the same shell to run the script on both machines? Check how you run the script, do `ls -lh /bin/sh`...

Comment: @Miquel: (Yes, this is late.) The `< $input` is valid. It redirects the input of the entire `while ... done` loop from the file named by `$input`.

Answer (score 0):

If it runs on one machine but not another, then there are differences in the script files on the different machines. Perhaps you have different line endings on one machine -- check them both with `dos2unix`